# simpledateformat unexpected results

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I am trying to format a string date as follows:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
Date d = df.parse("11-02-2012");
```

However, when I inspect the d variable it is:  "Wed Dec 02 00:00:00 EST 16" (12/02/2016)

Can anyone help me properly format this so, I get the right results?

Comment: are you setting this date instance to Calendar ?

Comment: that is all I am doing.  after that line I am just returning d, which is the line I am inspecting on.  Right after the parse it is incorrect

Comment: @rsoni: You mean you are seeing DEC instead of NOV?

Comment: yes, and 2016 instead of 2012

Comment: The code you posted works fine in JDK6.  It would seem there's something else happening you've left out.  Is that someone else's custom implementation of SimpleDateFormat?  Is the input string arriving from some framework?  (The fact that is says '16' instead of '2016' is somewhat indicative that something is up that you didn't include in your post.)

Comment: post the code where you are printing as well

Comment: Post a fully (simple) working example that demonstrates the problem as nobody seems to be able to reproduce the behaviour you observed.

Comment: 16 is not short for 2016, it means the year 16, which leads one to think that one of the strings in the actual program is not in the format you have assumed, and it is reading the year as 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the correct value:

```
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Test
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    new Test();
  }

  public Test()
  {
    try
    {
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
    Date d = df.parse("11-02-2012");

    System.out.println(d);
    }
    catch(Exception e) { }
  }
}
```

And I get

```
Fri Nov 02 00:00:00 UTC 2012
```

What TimeZone do you have set?